# Muti Repos' Github Pages use one top domain

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I have 3 github projects, and each has its own gh-pages.
We denote them: meta, cn, en
I want to implement the following:

```
www.example.com direct to meta's page
www.example.com/cn direct to cn's page
www.example.com/en direct to en's page
```

I guess that if I add a `CNAME`-record in my dns: @ points to `myusername.github.io` and add a file `CNAME` with content `example.com` in branch meta's gh-pages.

and then open `example.com` can show contents of meta

but I `example.com/cn/` will direct to the `404.html` page of meta instead of opening cn project's page.

Comment: Hi @stackpop - your question is, in my opinion, not easy to understand. I'd like to ask you to improve and clarify the question a bit more.

Comment: @stackpop, please add a link to your repo on GitHub for meta. It sounds like you've set this up correctly but I need to take a look to understand what might be wrong.

Comment: Have you read the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages) on setting up a custom domain? See also the custom domain [troubleshooting article](https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working).

Comment: thanks all, I solve it via the documentation Joel Govier provide